# c++ compare unordered_map hash keys

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to compare 2 std::unordered_map in order to check if they have the same keys and corresponding values.

Map keys are string and to gain some performace I'd like to know if it's possible to compare their computed hashes rather than the original string values (without caring about the possible "false positives" due to collisions).

Is there a simple way to achieve that?
Something like:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass*> map1;
std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass*> map2;
[...]

// make sure maps have the same size
auto itor1 = map1.begin();
auto itor2 = map2.begin();
while(itor1 != map1.end()){

   // compare itor1 and itor2 hashed key
   ++itor1; ++itor2;       
}
```

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by 'comparing' maps? Are you trying to see if a key present in one map is also present in another? Than simply iterate over first map and for every key there do find() in another map. This will be fastest way of achiving this.

Comment: That is what I'm going right now. I was wondering if the hashes were stored/accessible anywhere, so to iterate through the maps and compare them, saving the time for the key hash and find() for every entry.

Answer (score 1):

Most hash table implementations don't store the computed hash of a given item anywhere. The hash is only used to derive the bucket. And since the two maps may have different numbers of buckets, you can't even compare by bucket index.

So, bottom line: You can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could tackle this is to use a pair as your value in the map. The pair could be made of the type of your hash value and the type of your data. When inserting into your map, hash the key and pass it with your data as a pair. You could then do key-hash comparisons. As someone said above, hash values are not stored as they are only used when accessing.

This being said, hashing changes depending on the size of the container, so you'd run into other problems.